# Why do I have different results calculating True Positive rate in Keras Neural Network?

Tags: python, callback, keras, neural-network, metrics

I'm training a neural network using Python Keras package. I care about the True Positive rate, so I added it to Callbacks and Metrics. Surprisingly, I'm getting different results using the same formula (Callbacks shows 81%, which is correct: I can see the same manually after I join Labels and Predictions; Metrics shows higher, around 86%). What is the matter? Any comment on the code is also appreciated

```
def sensitivity(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)) * K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(y_true)
    return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
....
def calculate_rates(model, data, label):
    num_positive_prediction = np.sum(label)
    prediction = np.round(np.clip(model.predict(data, batch_size = 1024)[:,1], 0, 1))
    true_positive = np.sum(np.multiply(prediction, label)) / num_positive_prediction
    return(true_positive)
....
class TestCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, is_train, data, labels):
        self.data = data
        self.labels = labels[:,1]
        self.is_train = is_train

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        true_positive = calculate_rates(model, self.data, self.labels)
        if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0 or epoch == 0:
            if self.is_train:
                print("Epoch: %d" % epoch + 1)
                print("Training Set:")
            else:
                print("Testing Set:")
            print("True Positive Rate: %4g" % true_positive)
....
model = keras.Sequential()
my_init = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.1)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=200, activation='relu', input_dim=num_variables))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 200, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=my_init, bias_initializer=my_init))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=num_outputs, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=my_init, bias_initializer=my_init))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8),
              metrics=[sensitivity]
              )
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1024, class_weight={0: 1, 1: weight},
                    callbacks=[TestCallback(1, train_data, train_labels), TestCallback(0, test_data, test_labels)], verbose=1)
```

Comment: It might be because `sensitivity` is computed for a single batch of samples, whereas `calculate_rates` is computed for the full dataset.

Comment: The batch size is definitely affecting the `sensitivity` function: when I use values close to the dataset dimension, the two function give similar results. I found one more: `y_true` and `y_pred` are nx2 matrices, so I should use `y_true[:,1]` and `[y_pred[:,1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, you can use true positive, true negative, false positive, and false negative as metrics, then calculate True Positive Rate manually.

Here modification to your code...

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(), tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(), 
                       tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
                      ]
              )

_, tp,tn,fp,fn = model.evaluate(data, target)

# calculate True Positive Rate (tpr)
tpr = tp/(tp+fn)
```